# VSCode intellisense for python's dict.setdefault value

Tags: python

Is there a way to tell Python's intellisense in VSCode that a variable returned from dict.setdefault is a certain type?

```py
gens = {}
gen = 1

# How can I tell VSCode's intellisense/LSP that the types variable is a dict?
types = gens.setdefault(gen, {})
```

Comment: Use a type hint for that variable?

Comment: How do I that for python code?

Comment: `types: dict = gens.setdefault(gen, {})`

Comment: Ah ha!  I just found this.  Didn't realize they called them "type annotations" so I never searched the right thing.